# Mandar a imprimir PDF en Angular, sin abrir el modal de confirmación y sin abrir la ventana de vista previa

Tags: html5, angular

Estoy intentando imprimir un PDF con algunos datos para generar un ticket, y estoy necesitando que se comience a descargar al hacer click en un botón, sin vista previa del PDF, y sin el modal de confirmación.
Estuve probando con las librerias jsPDF y PDFMake, en ambas tuve el mismo inconveniente, y termine optando por PDFMake que me pareció un poco mejor. Acá les dejo un poco del codigo:

```
  generatePDF() {
    var win = window.open('', '_self');
    setTimeout (() => {
        const documentDefinition = {
          content: 'CONTENIDO DEL PDF'
        };
        pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).print({}, win);
    }, 1000)
  }
```

Con esto pude hacer que no se abra una nueva ventana con la vista previa del PDF, pero al hacer esto, no se abre el modal y mucho menos imprime. Si dejo solo el print() sin parametros, me abre una nueva ventana con el PDF y el modal para aceptar la impresión.

Existe alguna otra forma en la que pueda enviar a imprimir un conjunto de datos html y typescript, con solo un click?

Es para un sistema local, en donde se tiene un Tótem con un turnero, y necesito que cuando se elija una de las 2 opciones de turno, me imprima un ticket.

Comment: Acceder a un recurso de hardware (una impresora en este caso) siempre va a requerir una acción por parte del usuario. Imagina la de posibilidades si con sólo JS se puediera controlar el hardware del cliente de la forma que nos diera la gana. Por motivos de seguridad, los navegadores no permiten este comportamiento, por lo tanto, dudo mucho que logres encontrar una solución sin usar algún *plugin* instalado previamente por el cliente.

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras gracias por responder. Conoces algún plugin que pueda servirme? El sistema va a estar únicamente en un Tótem con un turnero, y necesito que cuando se elija una de las 2 opciones de turno, me imprima un ticket. Por lo que la seguridad, quizás, no sea un problema.

Comment: puedes usar electronjs, no es un plugin como tal es una aplicación de escritorio que usa javascript y node, es muy sencillo de usar e implementar, y puedes tener acceso a sistema e impresoras.

Comment: bueno gracias @EduardoJaramilloLicea voy a tenerlo en cuenta, si no encuentro alguna forma de hacerlo, tendré que cambiar de herramientas.